# Libreoffice Draw Transparency for png file

Tags: libreoffice

When exporting Libreoffice Draw as a .png file, it offers the choice of exporting using transparency. However, this option does not seem to work at all on the exported image. Is it a bug, or do we need to do something extra? It would be a very nice feature to get working.

Comment: When the background of the pages is set to "none" it should work.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this option. Where do I edit the background?

Comment: Right click on the page and in context menu select `page->page setup`. Or from the main menu, select `Format->Page/Slide Properties`. In tab `background` set "Fill" to "none".

Comment: i see. well i have checked and it was already set to none. so i think there must be something else for the transparency to be enabled.

Comment: How did you check transparency? Does `display <file.png>` not show the gray squared background?

Comment: 2 ways. in linux, image viewer shows a checked background when transparency works. also, when image is imported into GIMP, i can see that there is no background on the image and can move directly into position. neither works with the save being produced.

Comment: When I try it works as expected. Maybe you have a large filled rectangle covering all the page?

Answer (score 1):

In LibreOffice Impress...

CLICK Slide | Master Background
Set Slide Background --> "None"

Export the slide to an image format that supports an Alpha channel.
.png is a common one.

FILE | Export | choose "PNG - Portable Network Graphic (.png)"

In the export menu verify that "Save Transparency" is enabled with a check mark.

Browse for and open the image in an image viewer such as Ristretto.

The background should be checkerboard of light and dark grey squares.
This denotes the alpha channel (transparent part)

This is very useful for making titles for videos.
I set the aspect ratio of the slide the same as the video.
E.g. 1920 X 1080. I then create the title text with my preferred font, etc.
Then after exporting I can overlay the image over my video track and the text nicely overlays the video without having to mess around with color keying.